# File type icon not displaying correctly for some applications

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, icons

[image: Some file type icons not displaying correctly]
For example here, `.rb`, `.py`, `.pdf` icons are shown on top of an empty file icon, while the others are correct.

Tried rebuild `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/IconCache.db` and reboot, which didn't help. Also reset the default applications for the type, turned out that this seems to be an issue with certain applications, rather than file types.

Comment: Did they look fine previously? What does the registry say those file types' **DefaultIcon** is set to? If  you aren't comfortable with the registry use [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) and tell us.

Comment: Yes, FilteTypeMan can reset it, but need too many steps to fix just one type. Do you know how to locate it in registry and any easier ways to fix it? Also what caused this issue? Thanks for the prompt reply by the way.

Comment: I reckon it's application based issue, so I want to reset the icon for `Notepad++`, rather than `.txt`, `.rb` etc. respectively.

Comment: Somehow the DefaultIcon entry seems to have been modified for only those few file types, but what caused it I can't say. Fixing it via FTM would be easier than going into the registry, HKCR\.extension, looking up its ProgID, then going to HKCR\ProgID, modifying the DefaultIcon ... Edit: If you feel it's a problem with an app, say NP++, going into NP++'s settings, de-associating file types and then re-associating should fix it.

Comment: @Karan: Yes, looks like it may work for Notepad++, but in windows explorer, you can set anything to be open with NP++, but NP++ setting only provides limit types. For SublimeText2 and Evince, they don't even have this functionality.

Comment: Obviously if you've associated some extensions with an app that isn't associated with them by default, you'll have to fix the icons manually.

Comment: @Karan: Oh well, looks like the case.

Comment: Tried re-install evince, didn't fix `.pdf` icon.